# Using Laravel on a subdomain, where to put public files when have another website on main directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently, I have my live website hosted in the normal way with all files in public_html.

However, I am rewriting my website using Laravel but wish to test it first on a subdomain.

If I am not mistaken, to use Laravel on a live website you should upload all files into the host root except the public files. Which then should be uploaded into the public_html folder.

However how do I go about this when using the subdomain?

I have a structure as so:

```
root
  -- public_html
  -- subdomains
    -- beta
```

I could upload all files into beta and create a public folder inside that beta subdomain for the public files? I have tried this but get all sorts of path errors with double public_html/public_html paths etc. Nothing I try seems to work.

I want to keep the live site in tact, but work on the beta version stand alone when I need live testing.

Any help?

Comment: For subdomains you need to setup a virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

make a soft link by using: 
`ln -s /path/to/public_html/ /path/to/subdomains/beta/public`